# Subsection in header

Tags: header-footer

I use \pagestyle{fancy}. I would like to keep my current layout in the header and footer (some page with nothing in the header and/or footer other pages with arabic numbers and other again with rome numbers).

I would like the left side of the header to have the name of the section or subsection automatically (Not subsubsection).

How can I do that?

My tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

%Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{prefacestyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lhead{}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
    \lhead{Section or Subsection}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{Name}
    \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
Frontpage
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
Titlepage


\newpage\pagestyle{prefacestyle}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Preface
\newpage
Abstract
\newpage
Acknowlegdement
\newpage
Contents


\newpage\pagestyle{documentstyle}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\subsection{Related work}
\newpage
\section{Theory}
\newpage
\subsection{method 1}
\newpage
\subsubsection{part 1.1}
\newpage
\subsubsection{part 1.2}
\newpage
\subsection{method 2}
\newpage
\subsubsection{part 2.1}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit it if you want else.  Just edit here:

\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
    \lhead{**\leftmark**}
    \chead{**\rightmark**}
    \rhead{Name}
    \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.